# magento 2 migrate from local to cloud server

Tags: magento2

how to move magento 2community edition .zip file to cloud server

uploading through ftp it take too much time how to upload through putty by Magento cli commands

Comment: Try scp commands

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (fastest) way might be to connect from you local machine to the cloud over SCP and than transfer a ZIP file.

Syntax:

`scp <source> <destination>`

To copy a file from B to A while logged into B:
`scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination`

To copy a file from B to A while logged into A:
`scp username@b:/path/to/file /path/to/destination`

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh

Alternative methods might be rsync over SSH.